# Julia automatically inferring columns dataype of DataFrame (equivalent of pd.infer_objects())

Tags: dataframe, julia

Coming from Python, I started using Julia for its speed in a big-data project. When reading data from .xlsx files, the datatype in each column is "any", despite most of the data being integers or floats.

Is there any Julia-way of inferring the datatypes in a DataFrame (like `df = infertype.(df)`)?
This may be difficult in Julia, given the reduced flexibility on dataypes, but any tips on how to accomplish it would be appreciated. Assume, ex-ante, I do not know which column is which, but the types can only be int, float, string or date.

```
Using DataFrames
Using XLSX

df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("MyFile.xlsx", "Sheet1")...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("MyFile.xlsx", "Sheet1"; infer_eltypes=true)...)
```

Additionally, it is worth knowing that typing in Julia `?` before the command shows help that can contain such information:

```
help?> XLSX.readtable
  readtable(filepath, sheet, [columns]; [first_row], [column_labels], [header], [infer_eltypes], [stop_in_empty_row], [stop_in_row_function]) -> data, column_labels

  Returns tabular data from a spreadsheet as a tuple (data, column_labels). (...)

(...)

  Use infer_eltypes=true to get data as a Vector{Any} of typed vectors. The default value is infer_eltypes=false.

(...)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - and thank you for helping me help myself going forward:)